# automate Control + c in serial port in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to kill an `iperf` server session that opens on a serial port.

The code below opens the port, starts the `iperf` server, and copies the output to a single file.  At end of job, I tried to kill the server with `^C` − as expected, this didn't work since the server is in *listen* mode, I send any key-press through the `iperf` interactive listen shell; this doesn't stop it.

Closing the server port didn't help, as the server stays in *listen* mode. How can I kill the `iperf` server session by sending a command?

I tried adding the `iperf` server option `-t 20`, but this didn't work.

Truly appreciated for any help.

```
import serial
import time

port = "COM10"
baud = 115200
ser = serial.Serial(port, baud, timeout=5)

if ser.isOpen():
    print(ser.name + ' is open...')

print ('Iperf server session is running')
ser.write("\r\niperf -s -i 1 -w 1M")

log1 = ser.read(100000)
time.sleep(20)
print log1

with open('myoutput.txt') as f:
    last = None
    for line in (line for line in f if line.rstrip('\n')):
        last = line
        print last
        result = last[-14:]
        print result
        output = result[:4]
        print output
ser.write("\r\n ^c")
log2 = ser.read(1000)
print log2
ser.close()
```

Comment: Can you fix your indentation please. This is really hard to read.

Comment: What are you talking to? It's impossible to help you if you don't give all elements.

Comment: Won't be following, but as generic hints, you can try to send `\x03`, the actual character that the ascii control code represents. You can also try to send a BREAK on the serial line. Those are two common ways to represent what you want. But in the end, it depends on what you're talking to.

Comment: Fixed grammar.  I did my best to fix code indentation, but I can't be *sure* where the code blocks are supposed to end.

Comment: @spectras : Thanks for your effort.

Comment: due to time limit, i didn't keep sufficient information. The script runs on pycharm editor and output of result is redirected to 'myoutput.txt' file. Once i open the Iperf server session another script will send client traffic on this server port and Iperf server statistics will be copied to my output.txt file from there i will fetch the throughput number so far every thing works as expected. but Iperf server listening mode if is send any command this keeps in printing Iperf shell which doesn't make my command to execute. Control + c will kill the Iperf session, how can i send this key stoke?